# Store date in UK format (d-m-Y)

Tags: datepicker, octobercms

What is the best way to store a date in UK format (d-m-Y) rather than the default (Y-m-d) default in the backend of OctoberCMS?

Comment: There's good reason dates are stored in the ISO date format in the back-end. You should not change that. Only change the format when displaying dates to users.

Comment: Okay.

My issue is at the moment I have a date picker using the Y-m-d ISO format in order to search for course dates within a given period. Dates in the UK are formatted d-m-Y.  So how do I mutate it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the format in the YAML file. `Plugins/Author/Plugin/Models/PluginModel/fields.yaml` . Look at the [documentation here](https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/backend/forms.html#date-picker).

```
published_at:
    label: Published
    type: datepicker
    mode: date
    format: d-m-Y
```

If you are using the Builder plugin there is a spot for "format".
[image]